# ¿como codifico una cadena en json con php?

Tags: php, python, json, codeigniter

hola a todos lo que necesito es codificar una cadena que esta en formato json

en python es algo asi :

```
def queue(self, url, api_user, api_pass, api_version):
    args = urllib.urlencode({'cmd': 'api_queue_sms', 'username': api_user, 'password': api_pass, 'content': self.contenido, 'destination': self.destino, 'api_version': api_version})
```

pero yo necesito pasarlo a php lo que hecho es esto:

```
function queue($url, $api_user, $api_pass, $api_version){
        $args = urlencode('cmd': 'api_queue_sms', 'username': $api_user, 'password': $api_pass, 'content': $this->contenido, 'destination':  $this->destino, 'api_version': $api_version);
```

pero no me reconoce los ":" supongo que necesito algo para decirle que es json

espero su ayuda gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías solucionarlo de la siguiente forma:

- Crear un `array` asociativo con la información.
- Codificar el `array` a `JSON` utilizando la función [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)
- Por último codifica el `JSON` a `URL` utilizando la función [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php)

Ejemplo:

```
function queue($url, $api_user, $api_pass, $api_version) {
    $info = array(
      'cmd'=> 'api_queue_sms',
      'username'=> $api_user,
      'password'=> $api_pass,
      'content'=> $this->contenido,
      'destination'=> $this->destino,
      'api_version'=> $api_version
    );
    $args = urlencode(json_encode($info));
    /** bla bla bla */
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/GMXL73144)</kbd>

Comment: gracias me sirvio

Answer (score 1):

la función urlencode se la pasa un string y esos no el lo que estas pasando supongo que lo que quieres hacer es algo como esto:

```
   $json="{'nombre':'Omar','apellido':'Miranda'}";
   $codificado=urlencode($json);
```

Así ya tienes el json codificado ya después para recuperarlo solo tienes que hacer los siguiente:

```
  $json=urldecode($codificado);
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.